# Creating custom tiles for open street map

Tags: android, google-maps, maps

I need to create some map tiles for open street map.
I want them based on OS maps but I want to edit a particular section of the map in photoshop.

I have looked at mobile atlas creator (MOBAC) and can generate tile from the OS maps, but what I want to do is update the main map image first, then generate the tiles with my updates.

I don't think it's possible to do this with MOBAC so can anyone point me in the right direction of what I need to do?

Thanks Bex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found a way, use oziexplore to calibrate an image (or a map) and then load the .map file into Mapc2Mapc then generate the tiles in adnav format. Unfortunately then I need to rename all my tiles so they end in .tile rather than  .adnav for the default version of OSMDroid.

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard about MOBAC, but there is a company called CloudMade.
They provide different services around OpenStreetMap data. One of their service is Style Editor:
http://developers.cloudmade.com/projects/show/style-editor

You can create your own style of tiles, i.e. show/hide POIs, change colors for different types of roads, rivers and so on.

Is it what you need?